# Symfony2/twig issue rendering collection remove_btn

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

We are trying to render differently our form collection page straight from within the action template.

The issue we have is that we can't render the widget_remobe_btn button. For example, if we try `{{ form_widget(entity.name) }}` we get the name. But in this case we do not receive the button as we expect `{{ form_widget(entity.vars.widget_remove_btn) }}`.

If we add `{{ form_rest(entity) }}` (and so from within the foreach that prints each row per collection item), the "remove" buttons are removed from below the form but are not rendered where the form_widget tag sits.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {# render the task's only field: description #}

    <h3>Tags</h3>
        {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for entity in form.collection %}
                {{ form_start(entity) }}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(entity.name) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(entity.vars.widget_remove_btn) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {{ form_end(entity) }}
            {% endfor %}
            <tbody>
        </table>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Just in case it could be useful, we are using <kbd>MopaBootstrapBundle</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

We managed to get it working by using `form_row(entity)` instead of `row_rest()` or `row_widget()`, which ended up acting like `form_rest()` should; that is by outputting the button.

Here is the final code:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    <h2>Form</h2>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover collection-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Op</th>
                    <th>Operation</th>
                    <th>Tools</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for entity in form.entities %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form_widget(entity.name) }}</td>
                    {{ form_rest(entity) }}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tbody>
        </table>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Then, in order to make the button wowking - because we are using <kbd>MopaBootstrapBundle</kbd> - we added this snippet in out JavaScript file:

```
$('.collection-table').on('click.collection.data-api', '[data-collection-remove-btn]', function (e) {
    var $btn = $(e.target);

    if (! $btn.hasClass('btn')) {
        $btn = $btn.closest('.btn');
    }

    $btn.closest('tr').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```